# How to modally lock a macOS volume for exclusive read/write access?

Tags: macos, disk

I am writing a disk tool that needs to be able to read and possibly modify a live volume.

If the volume is in use, e.g. if it's the boot volume, one cannot simply unmount the volume to perform these operations.

Disk Utility (or the underlying `diskutil` tool) is able to lock a mounted volume for this purpose when it runs First Aid or when it resizes the startup volume through the "Partitions" dialog.

What API can I use in order to accomplish the same? I.e. what calls do I have to make to have the volume locked (and pending writes flushed), and, optionally, how do I best lock the UI so that the user can't accidentally use other apps that attempt to modify the volume in the meantime?

I am okay with private frameworks and other undocumented ways. This is for a repair program, after all. It won't appear in the Mac App Store ;)

Comment: Is private frameworks an option for you? You'll probably find useful stuff in the DiskManagement framework. Not sure if there's anything public.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `fcntl (fd, F_FREEZE_FS)` is the solution.

I found this call by looking into the code of the command `fsck_apfs`. It actually offers the "-l" option for "live fsck (lock down for verify-only)".

And now that I know what to look for, I realize that it's also documented in Amit Singh's Mac OS X Internals book.